# Scrapy: how to use items in spider and how to send items to pipelines?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am new to `scrapy` and my task is simple:

For a given e-commerce website:

- crawl all website pages
- look for products page
- If the URL point to a product page
- Create an Item
- Process the item to store it in a database

I created the spider but products are just printed in a simple file.

My question is about the project structure: how to use items in spider and how to send items to pipelines ?

I can't find a simple example of a project using items and pipelines.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

- How to use items in my spider?

Well, the main purpose of items is to store the data you crawled. `scrapy.Items` are basically dictionaries. To declare your items, you will have to create a class and add `scrapy.Field` in it:

```
import scrapy

class Product(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
```

You can now use it in your spider by importing your Product.

For advanced information, I let you check the doc [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html?#module-scrapy.item)

- How to send items to the pipeline ?

First, you need to tell to your spider to use your `custom pipeline`.

In the **settings.py** file:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipelines.CustomPipeline': 300,
}
```

You can now write your pipeline and play with your item.

In the **pipeline.py** file:

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class CustomPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Create your database connection

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # Here you can index your item
        return item
```

Finally, in your **spider**, you need to `yield` your item once it is filled.

**spider.py** example:

```
import scrapy
from myspider.items import Product

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ['http://www.exemple.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        doc = Product()
        doc['url'] = response.url
        doc['title'] = response.xpath('//div/p/text()')
        yield doc # Will go to your pipeline
```

Hope this helps, here is the doc for **pipelines**: [Item Pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Comment: What would you exactly put here? - `# Here you can insert your item`

Comment: In the exemple, the pipeline is used to insert the data you crawled into a database. In the `process_item` function, you will use the database api to index the crawled data in the database. So what I exactly put there depends of the database I use.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, would you mind inserting a an example?

Comment: actually `def __init(self)` and not `def __init__(self)`?!?!